# Chrome Dev tools stuck at retrieving timeline

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am not sure what the problem is here, but I am unable to record timeline in chrome devtool. I click on the start recording icon, and when I stop it, it just keeps saying `retrieving timeline`.

Chrome Version:  50.0.2661.102 (64-bit)
Operating System: OSX
I tried incognito and also deleted all my `/Application Support/Google/Chrome` files. Nothing worked.

Comment: Same here. 50.0.2661.102 m, Windows 7.

Comment: bug report https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=614860

Comment: Having this issue with www.redhat.com on Chrome 55.0.2883.87 (64-bit) on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Just reload it! If you are on a windows/apple computer then press f5. If you are on a chromebook press f3 (or the reload looking button) or You can look on the top left and press the reload button it.

I hope this works for you